# Create stationary dataset with log, sqrt and cube root layering

Tags: time-series, python, arima, stationarity

I have a time variant dataset with highly non stationary data. The dickey-fuller p value always at the 0.90 to 0.99 area. Even after single transformation, still data generates with p value about 0.80.I also tried with rolling mean and ewm as well. Is it possible to layer the dataset with first transform the values with logs. Then transform the dataset again with square root and finally with cube root?

```
data['columnA'] = np.log(data['columnA'])
data['columnA'] =np.sqrt(data['columnA'])
data['columnA'] =np.cbrt(data['columnA'])
```

Because that is the only way i was able to reduce p value to less that 0.01.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Could you explain what "layering a dataset" would be?  If you're asking about performing a sequence of transformations, please recognize that in general it won't even be defined: you can't take square roots of logarithms when the original value is less than 1, for instance.

Comment: ADF is about unit roots. It has really nothing to do with these types of transformations.